# How can I compile/install wordnet on a recent macOS?

Tags: command-line, install, spellcheck

I want install [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu) on macOS Mojave. I have downloaded [WordNet-3.0.tar.gz](http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/3.0/WordNet-3.0.tar.gz) and ran the `./configure` step, but it finished with the line

```
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: WARNING: Can't find Tcl configuration definitions
```

and no `Makefile` is created. I guess, Mojave doesn't include Tcl/Tk anymore.

Is there a way to install WordNet without the Tcl/Tk frontend? I  only need the `wn` cli tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install wordnet directly with homebrew using `brew install wordnet`.

If you don't want to do that, you can l tcl/tk with homebrew:

`brew install tcl-tk`

This should at least fix the tcl/tk error.

To **install homebrew** use the script from brew.sh

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: Wordnet itself is also available as brew package. So, I'd go with brew install wordnet.

Comment: Even better, I edited the answer, thanks @Volsk